# Jquery modal with confirmation is submited before user confirmation

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have users remove function with jquery and ajax. When user click `Delete` popup window appear and ask if he is sure or not with buttons `Yes` and `No`. The problem is that the script is performed and user is deleted in the moment of clicking `Delete`. It doesn't matter if user click `No`.

I use this jquery confirmation plugin:
https://myclabs.github.io/jquery.confirm/

And this is the jquery part

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('.delete').click(function() {
      var parent = $(this).closest('.header-profile');
      $.ajax({
         type: 'get',
         url: 'misc/friendRemove.php', 
         data: 'ajax=1&delete=' + $(this).attr('id'),
         beforeSend: function() {
            parent.animate({'backgroundColor':'#fb6c6c'},300);
         },

             success: function()
             {
                parent.fadeOut('slow', function() {$(this).remove();});
             }
      });                 
    });

    $('.delete').confirm({
       text: "Are you sure?",
       title: "Please confirm",

       confirmButton: "Yes",
       cancelButton: "No",
       post: true,
       confirmButtonClass: "btn-danger",
       cancelButtonClass: "btn-default",
       dialogClass: "modal-dialog modal-lg"
    });      
});
```

And the button

```
<a href="" class="delete" id="'.$row['id'].'"><i class="fa fa-times pull-right"></i></a>
```

Comment: put the function you've defined in the `$.click` into a `confirm:` option in your $.confirm - as per the documentation on the page you linked to - and don't make the button an `<a>` tag - there's other side effects you may need to code for - use `<button>` (as per example, again) or even a `<span>` will work

Comment: It would be nice to see a (non-)working snippet of this. Also, you seem to have a PHP remnant in your `<a>` that could be cleaned up.

Comment: I tried this but then I don't get the popup.

Comment: I was going to add, the code may need some changing because the `this` in the click code may not be the `this` you want it to be

Comment: With `<span>` instead of `<a>` I've got the popup but doesn't matther what I choose `Yes` or `No` the user is deleted.

Comment: Always delete the item and never mind what I click - `Yes` or `No`..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to call ajax delete method on `confirm` method. Below is the codes:

```
function deleteItem(parent, id){
            $.ajax({
             type: 'get',
             url: 'misc/friendRemove.php', 
             data: 'ajax=1&delete=' + id,
             beforeSend: function() {
                parent.animate({'backgroundColor':'#fb6c6c'},300);
             },

             success: function() {
                 parent.fadeOut('slow', function( {$(this).remove();});
             }
          });         
        }

    $(document).ready(function() {
        var parent, id;
        $('.delete').click(function(event) {
          parent = $(this).closest('.header-profile');
          id = $(this).attr('id');
          event.preventDefault();        
        });


        $('.delete').confirm({
           text: "Are you sure?",
           title: "Please confirm",
           confirmButton: "Yes",
           cancelButton: "No",
           post: true,
           confirmButtonClass: "btn-danger",
           cancelButtonClass: "btn-default",
           dialogClass: "modal-dialog modal-lg",
            confirm: function(button) {
            deleteItem(parent, id);
            }
        });      
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('.delete').click(function() {

        $(this).confirm({
            text: "Are you sure?",
            title: "Please confirm",

            confirm: function() {
                var parent = $(this).closest('.header-profile');
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'get',
                    url: 'misc/friendRemove.php',
                    data: 'ajax=1&delete=' + $(this).attr('id'),
                    beforeSend: function() {
                        parent.animate({'backgroundColor':'#fb6c6c'},300);
                    },

                    success: function()
                    {
                        parent.fadeOut('slow', function() {$(this).remove();});
                    }
                });
            },

            confirmButton: "Yes",
            cancelButton: "No",
            post: true,
            confirmButtonClass: "btn-danger",
            cancelButtonClass: "btn-default",
            dialogClass: "modal-dialog modal-lg"
        });

    });

});
```

That is, call ajax for user deletion only when the confirmation is received as from plugin's documentation: https://github.com/myclabs/jquery.confirm#options

Comment: Thank's but popup doesn't appear.. should I use `<a>` or?

Comment: The tag should not matter. Check your browser's console for any errors. To invoke the console press ctrl+shift+i and choose Console tab (for Chrome). Or just right click any element and choose Inspect element and then Console tab. Then try clicking the link/button.

Comment: Nothing in the Console. The popup is appear on second click on `<a>` and when I click `Yes` doesn't delete it.